# Excel Cell Match - Copy other data from sheet

Tags: excel

Basically I have a pretty simple sheet but I am struggling with it :(

Basically there are a few headings such as "Name", "Manager", "Credit"

I get a sheet that has a list of all Names etc and would like a macro to check if the Name is in the list and then to copy the credit cell from a sheet called "Agent" to a sheet called "Credit" have tried loads of solutions but to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Taking the Excel file that you shared as a reference, you could use the following *provided that your first column on the sheet `Agent` is sorted in ascending order*. In cell `C2` of sheet `Credit`, enter

```
=LOOKUP($A2,Agent!$A:$A,Agent!$B:$B)
```

Then select that cell `C2` and drag the lower-right corner down. This is the simplest version, but it will give strange results if a name from sheet `Credit` is not found on sheet `Agent`. A better version is

```
=IF($A2<>LOOKUP($A2,Agent!$A:$A,Agent!$A:$A),"Not Found",LOOKUP($A2,Agent!$A:$A,Agent!$B:$B))
```

The first part of the if checks to see if the Agent name is found on sheet `Agent`. If not, the result is "Not Found", otherwise the result is the same lookup as in the previous function.

Comment: +1 If there are many values to check, the second LOOKUP formula would be much faster than the VLOOKUP alternative (binary v linear search).

Comment: @lori_m Interesting, thanks for the comment and upvote. Are these implementation details documented anywhere?

Comment: A recent blog post here by Excel MVP Charles Williams: http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/

Answer (score 1):

When looking up LOOKUP vs VLOOKUP after reading lori_m's comment, I did not find anything regarding relative performance.  Mostly I found that LOOKUP is only still in Excel for legacy compatibility and VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP are more flexible.

However, I did come across a series of articles starting at http://exceluser.com/blog/420/excel%E2%80%99s-vlookup-vs-index-match-functions.html which suggest that INDEX and MATCH functions provide an even better solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was referring to VLOOKUP with last argument set to FALSE for exact match being slow. I'd expect the formula in you other post to be equivalent to the LOOKUP one in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Lookup`? This function finds a value in a single row or column and will do some matching against it in a different row or column.

Comment: I have tried a few things haven't tried Lookup yet any ideas what it would be?

Answer (score 0):

The key function you need is VLOOKUP which takes the Lookup_value (The name to search for which can be a cell reference), the Table_array (The range to look in - It searches the first column of this range for the Lookup_value, returning the first alphabetical match or the first value past the Lookup_value so the list must be sorted and the results compared to the Lookup_value to see if they really match) and the Col_index_number (first column is 1 - it returns value from this column).

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, Agent!$A:$B,1)=A2,VLOOKUP(A2, Agent!$A:$B,2),"No match")
```

This example will look up the value in A1 of the current sheet in the A column of the Agent sheet and return the value from the corresponding B column of the Agent sheet or "No match" if there isn't one.

Comment: I'm looking for a macro that will do it for me if possible as the Agent field will be populated all I need it to do is grab the data from the "Agent" Sheet and see if the name exists on the Sheet Named "Credit" and if it does to copy the cell "Credit" after the name

Comment: Using a function will provide much better performance than looping through cells in a macro.  I would only use a macro to help set up a scratch sheet with the data needed from other sheets and I would only do that if necessary.  Also, that macro can be recorded as you do it once as an example.

Comment: It's just stating No Match even though I have configured it

Comment: The first argument (Lookup_value) needs to be just one cell.  I expect if you give it a range (like A2:A7) it will only find the answer if all six cells match six cells (with nothing in between) in the Table_array.  In general, getting back "No match" means it didn't find a matching value for the Lookup_value in the first column of the Table_array.

Comment: Here is a copy of what I have so far? http://www.2shared.com/document/cmz5CmUg/credit.html

Comment: If you take the modified formula I put in my answer just now and drop it into cell C2 of the worksheet you provided, then copy it down, it should work.  You will need to sort the Agent Name column in the Agent sheet and try some names that actually match, but that is all.  BTW the function from Reinier Torenbeek's answer will also work.